# Laravel - Eloquent do not repeat yourself

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have code like this:

```
$totalCount = User::sum('count_fortress');

$lastVisit = User::orderBy('last_visit_fortress', 'DESC')->first('last_visit_fortress');

$topFiveUsers = User::whereNotNull(['count_fortress', 'last_visit_fortress'])
    ->orderBy('count_fortress', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('last_visit_fortress', 'DESC')
    ->get(['id', 'count_fortress', 'last_visit_fortress'])
    ->take(5);

return response()->json([
    "fortress" => [
        "total_count" => $totalCount,
        "last_visited" => $lastVisit->last_visit_fortress,
        "users" => $topFiveUsers
    ]
]);


$totalCount = User::sum('count_museum');

$lastVisit = User::orderBy('last_visit_museum', 'DESC')->first('last_visit_museum');

$topFiveUsers = User::whereNotNull(['count_museum', 'last_visit_museum'])
    ->orderBy('count_museum', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('last_visit_museum', 'DESC')
    ->get(['id', 'count_museum', 'last_visit_museum'])
    ->take(5);

return response()->json([
    "museum" => [
        "total_count" => $totalCount,
        "last_visited" => $lastVisit->last_visit_museum,
        "users" => $topFiveUsers
    ]
]);
```

Is there a possible way to make it in one method or something like put that logic in the repostiory or service instead of controller?

Comment: accept as an additional route param museum or fortress and then concatenate the param onto the end of each instance they're used

Comment: Can u show me the example, please?

Comment: You should look at local query scopes to make your queries reusable: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: @LobsterBaz can u explain me in advice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scope for reusing queries, in your User model define.

```
public function scopeTopFiveUsers(Builder $query, string $context) {
    ->whereNotNull(['count_' . $context, 'last_visit_' . $context])
    ->orderBy('count_' . $context, 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('last_visit_' . $context, 'DESC')
    ->select(['id', 'count_' . $context, 'last_visit_' . $context])
}
```

Since there is a correlation between the two solutions, you can use some clever use of column names and access properties based on strings with `{}`. This solution is on the edge of being to clever, but this is a solution with the mindset of don't repeat your self. Also utilized the scope solution.

```
private function calculateResponse(string $context) {
    $topFiveUsers = User::topFiveUsers($context)->take(5);
    $lastVisit = User::orderBy('last_visit_' . $context, 'DESC')->first('last_visit_' . $context)->{'last_visit_' . $context};

    return [
        'total_count' => User::sum('count_' . $context),
        'last_visited' => $lastVisit,
        'users' => $topFiveUsers
    ]
}

public function controllerMethodOne() {
    return response()->json([
        "fortress" => [
            $this->calculateResponse('fortress');
        ]
    ]);
}

public function controllerMethodTwo() {
    return response()->json([
        "museum" => [
            $this->calculateResponse('museum');
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create global scopes as previously suggested, however if this is just being used as a single instance, then i'd probably go for something like this:

```
Route::get('user/{type?}', function ($name) {
    //point to your controller
})->where('type', 'museum|fortress');
```

And then in your controller which of course name what you want..

```
function genericSharedFunction($type){

    $totalCount = User::sum('count_'.$type);

    $lastVisit = User::orderBy('last_visit_'.$type, 'DESC')->first('last_visit_'.$type);

    $topFiveUsers = User::whereNotNull(['count_'.$type, 'last_visit_'.$type])
        ->orderBy('count_'.$type, 'DESC')
        ->orderBy('last_visit_'.$type, 'DESC')
        ->get(['id', 'count_'.$type, 'last_visit_'.$type])
        ->take(5);

    $last_visit_prop = 'last_visit_'.$type;

    return response()->json([
        "$type" => [
            "total_count" => $totalCount,
            "last_visited" => $lastVisit->$last_visit_prop,
            "users" => $topFiveUsers
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to replace `museum` with `$type` in the `whereNotNull` clause